# JavaFX embedded (in browser) code doesn't start

Tags: java, javafx-2

It's giving me this error.

```
MissingFieldException[ The following required field is missing from the launch file: <jnlp>]
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory._buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.initManager(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Error while initializing manager: MissingFieldException[ The following required field is missing from the launch file: <jnlp>], bail out
```

What's even more strange to me is that it works If I'm opening html file manually, but not working if I'm using this file in my django applicaiton.

All files have been created in IDEA 13 comminity edition

```
<html><head>
  <SCRIPT src="http://java.com/js/dtjava.js"></SCRIPT>
<script>
    function launchApplication(jnlpfile) {
        dtjava.launch(            {
                url : 'Duplicate.jnlp'
            },
            {
                javafx : '2.2+'
            },
            {}
        );
        return false;
    }
</script>

<script>
    function javafxEmbed_Duplicate_id() {
        dtjava.embed(
            {
                id : 'Duplicate_id',
                url : 'Duplicate.jnlp',
                placeholder : 'javafx-app-placeholder',
                width : 600,
                height : 400
            },
            {
                javafx : '2.2+'
            },
            {}
        );
    }
    <!-- Embed FX application into web page once page is loaded -->
    dtjava.addOnloadCallback(javafxEmbed_Duplicate_id);
</script>

</head><body>
<h2>Test page for <b>Duplicate</b></h2>
  <b>Webstart:</b> <a href='Duplicate.jnlp' onclick="return launchApplication('Duplicate.jnlp');">click to launch this app as webstart</a><br><hr><br>

  <!-- Applet will be inserted here -->
  <div id='javafx-app-placeholder'></div>
</body></html>
```

That's the html file.

That's the jnlp file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="Duplicate.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Title</title>
    <vendor>vendor</vendor>
    <description>dfsdf</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="Duplicate.jar" size="24699" download="eager" />
    <jar href="commons-codec-1.6.jar" size="232771" download="eager" />
    <jar href="commons-logging-1.1.3.jar" size="62050" download="eager" />
    <jar href="fluent-hc-4.3.3.jar" size="28696" download="eager" />
    <jar href="gson-2.2.4.jar" size="190418" download="eager" />
    <jar href="httpasyncclient-4.0.1.jar" size="157516" download="eager" />
    <jar href="httpasyncclient-cache-4.0.1.jar" size="33811" download="eager" />
    <jar href="httpclient-4.3.3.jar" size="589512" download="eager" />
    <jar href="httpclient-cache-4.3.3.jar" size="149800" download="eager" />
    <jar href="httpcore-4.3.2.jar" size="282269" download="eager" />
    <jar href="httpcore-nio-4.3.2.jar" size="316524" download="eager" />
    <jar href="httpmime-4.3.3.jar" size="37274" download="eager" />
    <jar href="jfxutils-0.3.jar" size="30866" download="eager" />
    <jar href="org.json-20120521.jar" size="40375" download="eager" />
    <jar href="unirest-java-1.3.8.jar" size="35161" download="eager" />
  </resources>
  <applet-desc  width="600" height="400" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="Duplicate" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="600" height="400" main-class="sample.Main"  name="Duplicate" />
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

That's the django view that return html

```
def chart(request):
    html = open('Duplicate.html')
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: what is content of your Duplicate jnlp?

Comment: looks good. Let's look at how do you open it in your django application? What do you mean by that?

Comment: I've updated the question. I suspect that this issue could be connected with the fact that I haven't signed the jar.

But I don't signed that because first - I don't know how to do that. Second: I don't wanna do that (because this applet is only for internal use).

Comment: nothing wrong in django as well. I see next options: you have wrong jnlp in browser cache, try to clean it; or you load wrong jnlp due to relative paths -- try to use absolute paths in html.

Comment: I've tried to clean chrome cache. I've tried to clean java cache in java plugin control panel. It still doesn't work. And it loading the applet infinitely in firefox.

Comment: Ok, then can you try to open the console and check if there any additional info in there: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml

Comment: Well, I've edited the post with full stack trace. The console was opened all the time. Кстати, мы можем общаться по-русски =)

Comment: I think I now the reason for that. It seemes that the browser just can't load this jnlp file, when it getting it from web-server.

Comment: So the question is how to point it to that file?

Comment: in this case it's a problem of web server, why can't he provide file correctly?

Comment: Well... I just don't know how to that?
In javascript there is a line
url : 'Duplicate.jnlp',

But where this file should be? In the same folder on the server as the script? Well, that's how it is now, but it's not working.

Comment: did you tried to enter absolute path like I advised 3 comments above? :)

Comment: Yes, with the same result.

Comment: I've run out of ideas, maybe check if your webserver provides correct MIME-type for jnlp file `application/x-java-jnlp-file`

Comment: AFAIK it's not helping. I've tried to use django view to return this jnlp file with this MIME-type and with the same result.